# Erro no "utf-8" no python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema no python 3 que no código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.biz/prices.html")

text = page.read().decode('utf8')

print(text)`
```

dá o **erro**:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1265: invalid continuation byte`

e não sei o que fazer para consertar

Observação: ainda sou iniciante na programação, esse código faz parte do livro "use a cabeça programação", e o objetivo dele e "mostrar" o site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece na seguinte linha:

```
text = page.read().decode('utf8')
```

Ele tenta decodificar a página do site supracitado usando codificação UTF-8, mas falha ao encontrar algum byte mal formado. O conteúdo da página é o seguinte:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ja,en"><script type="text/javascript">\r\n\r\n  var _gaq = _gaq || [];\r\n  _gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-20569835-2\']);\r\n  _gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);\r\n\r\n  (function() {\r\n    var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;\r\n    ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';\r\n    var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\r\n  })();\r\n\r\n</script><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body oncontextmenu="return false;" style="width: 100% !important; height: 2600px !important;">\r\n<center><a href="http://cgi.i-mobile.co.jp/ad_link.aspx?guid=on&asid=32341&pnm=0&asn=1"><img border="0" src="http://cgi.i-mobile.co.jp/ad_img.aspx?guid=on&asid=32341&pnm=0&asn=1&asz=0&atp=2&lnk=6666ff&bg=&txt=000000&pbb=1"></a></center>\r\n<center><a href="http://cgi.i-mobile.co.jp/ad_link.aspx?guid=on&asid=32341&pnm=0&asn=2"><img border="0" src="http://cgi.i-mobile.co.jp/ad_img.aspx?guid=on&asid=32341&pnm=0&asn=2&asz=0&atp=2&lnk=6666ff&bg=&txt=000000"></a></center>\r\n\r\n\r\n<center><FONT SIZE="2">ﾐﾝﾅ�ﾎが選んだ�ｩ11/07のﾗﾝｷﾝｸﾞ�ｿ</FONT></center>\r\n<center><FONT SIZE="2">�ｿ ��位 �ｿ</FONT></center>\r\n\r\n<br>\r\n<center><FONT SIZE="2">�ｿ ��位 �ｿ</FONT></center>\r\n\r\n<a name="madop"></a>\r\n<br>\r\n<center><font size="2">他のｷｰﾜｰﾄﾞで探してみる</FONT></center><center>\r\n<form method="get" action="/genre23.php">\r\n<font size="2"><input type="text" name="query2" value="" size="8"><font size="4">\r\n<SELECT name="genre">\r\n<OPTION value="3">��</OPTION>\r\n\r\n</SELECT>\r\n</FONT><input type="submit" value=" 探す�ﾏ "></FONT>\r\n<input type="hidden" name="cache" value=""><input type="hidden" name="fname" value="">\r\n</form>\r\n</center><br>\r\n<center><font size="2" color="red"><b><a href="/inq/disclaimer.php?ngdom=beans-r-us.biz&ngk=retire%20your%20vehicle">利用規約・削除依頼</a></b></FONT></center>\r\n<br></body></html>'
```

Como pode ver, há vários caracteres orientais presentes. É provável que ele tenha encontrado problemas em decodificar algum desses.

Comment: Então como faço para funcionar?

Comment: Se sua intenção é só fazer o script funcionar, então pode tentar tirar a parte do `.decode('utf8')`

Comment: É funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Fiz o mesmo exemplo sem precisar remover o .decode("utf-8"), que deu a mesma resposta tirando ele.O exemplo do livro coloca no final do site .html, remova e você vai obter o mesmo resultado.

Ps: uso o python 3